# ngTableP search functinality working on first page only when I kept search box out of the table

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am new to angularjs
When I use search functionality works on first page only not on all the pages

search box

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="campId.campaign_id" placeholder="Search here...">
```

In my html

```
<table ng-table="tableParams"  class="table table-striped">
                    <tr ng-repeat="campaign in $data| filter: campId">
```

// my data hare
// if I added filter inside table then only its works here it will work for name

```
<td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'" filter = "{ 'name':'text' }">  <div contenteditable="true"> 
                            {{campaign.name}}</div>
                    </td>

                    </tr>
            </table>
```

Below is js code for pagination

```
 campaign.controller('campaignController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', '$http', function($scope, $filter, ngTableParams, $http) {
        $http.get("api/test")
                .success(function(response) {
                    $scope.feilds = response.campaigns;
                    var length_of_dict = Object.keys($scope.feilds).length;
                    var keys_list = Object.keys($scope.feilds);
                    var data = $scope.feilds;
                    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                        page: 1, // show first page
                        count: 2 ,  // count per page
                       filter : {
                           campaign_id : ''     // initial sorting
                        }
                    }, {
                        total: length_of_dict, // length of data
                        getData: function($defer, params) {
                            // use build-in angular filter
                            //alert(params) ;
                            var orderedData = params.filter() ?
                                    $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : //This will be used to filter the dictionary array and return back only those resource objects that has the desired key the user is looking for.

                                data;
                            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        }
                    });
                });
    }]);
```

Comment: Wow, that's unfortunate. What is your question? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Its only search in first page only..not on all the pages..

Comment: Is it normal that the search text goes into "campId.campaign_id" whereas the filter is on "campId" ?

Comment: create a demo that replicates the problem

Comment: @bvaile Its working ..Can I pass whole data to filter I think here only slice of data is getting filtered.